# How can I modify pagination to restrict shown page numbers?

Tags: 8, paging

I have a pagination for list of articles within a Drupal site  e.g.:

```
<<first <previous ... 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... next> last>>
```

So at the moment there are always nine page links shown. Basically I want to find out how to modify this so there are (for example) only five links and the text for labels for the controls in the pager like this:

```
<< < ... 6 7 8 9 10 ... > >>
```

I wrote this code with not result:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_pager().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_pager(&$variables) {
  $variables['quantity'] = 5;
  $variables['tags'] = ["«", "‹", "›", "»"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that at the point you're trying to modify the quantity, the pager items have already been generated so your quantity value doesn't have any effect.

Similar to Drupal 7, I believe you're going to need to implement the full pager function, just copying the core pager function to your theme and changing the quantity.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_pager(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  $quantity = 5; // hardcode your quantity here
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

  // Nothing to do if there is only one page.
  if ($pager_total[$element] <= 1) {
    return;
  }

  $tags = $variables['tags'];

  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
  $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // first is the first page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_first = $pager_current - $pager_middle + 1;
  // last is the last page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_last = $pager_current + $quantity - $pager_middle;
  // max is the maximum page number
  $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
  // End of marker calculations.

  // Prepare for generation loop.
  $i = $pager_first;
  if ($pager_last > $pager_max) {
    // Adjust "center" if at end of query.
    $i = $i + ($pager_max - $pager_last);
    $pager_last = $pager_max;
  }
  if ($i <= 0) {
    // Adjust "center" if at start of query.
    $pager_last = $pager_last + (1 - $i);
    $i = 1;
  }
  // End of generation loop preparation.

  // Create the "first" and "previous" links if we are not on the first page.
  if ($pager_page_array[$element] > 0) {
    $items['first'] = array();
    $options = array(
      'query' => pager_query_add_page($parameters, $element, 0),
    );
    $items['first']['href'] = \Drupal::url('<current>', [], $options);
    if (isset($tags[0])) {
      $items['first']['text'] = $tags[0];
    }

    $items['previous'] = array();
    $options = array(
      'query' => pager_query_add_page($parameters, $element, $pager_page_array[$element] - 1),
    );
    $items['previous']['href'] = \Drupal::url('<current>', [], $options);
    if (isset($tags[1])) {
      $items['previous']['text'] = $tags[1];
    }
  }

  if ($i != $pager_max) {
    // Add an ellipsis if there are further previous pages.
    if ($i > 1) {
      $variables['ellipses']['previous'] = TRUE;
    }
    // Now generate the actual pager piece.
    for (; $i <= $pager_last && $i <= $pager_max; $i++) {
      $options = array(
        'query' => pager_query_add_page($parameters, $element, $i - 1),
      );
      $items['pages'][$i]['href'] = \Drupal::url('<current>', [], $options);
      if ($i == $pager_current) {
        $variables['current'] = $i;
      }
    }
    // Add an ellipsis if there are further next pages.
    if ($i < $pager_max) {
      $variables['ellipses']['next'] = TRUE;
    }
  }

  // Create the "next" and "last" links if we are not on the last page.
  if ($pager_page_array[$element] < ($pager_max - 1)) {
    $items['next'] = array();
    $options = array(
      'query' => pager_query_add_page($parameters, $element, $pager_page_array[$element] + 1),
    );
    $items['next']['href'] = \Drupal::url('<current>', [], $options);
    if (isset($tags[3])) {
      $items['next']['text'] = $tags[3];
    }

    $items['last'] = array();
    $options = array(
      'query' => pager_query_add_page($parameters, $element, $pager_max - 1),
    );
    $items['last']['href'] = \Drupal::url('<current>', [], $options);
    if (isset($tags[4])) {
      $items['last']['text'] = $tags[4];
    }
  }

  $variables['items'] = $items;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score -1):

With Drupal 8 it's just a simple setting. You can change the number of pages shown (defaults to 9).

Structure > Views > Select your view

Click edit

It's in the center options area.

Comment: This works for views, but the question isn't specifically about views.